# What function should I implement to return a selected picture from gallery? iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

What function should I implement to return a selected picture from gallery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html).  In this example, I'm using the built-in image cropper as well.

```
- (void) showImage {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
    imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject: (NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
    [self presentModalViewController: imagePickerController animated: YES];
}

- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info {
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.editedImage = image;
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}

- (void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel: (UIImagePickerController *) picker {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}
```

This will allow the user to pick an image.  If you don't want the cropping, set `imagePickerController.allowsEditing = NO` and use the key `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` to get the resulting image back.